# mysql working with trees

Tags: mysql, tree

I got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE 'category' (
    'id' INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    'parent_category_id' INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    'name' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    INDEX 'parent_category_id' ('parent_category_id'),
    CONSTRAINT 'category_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('parent_category_id') REFERENCES 'category' ('id')
) COLLATE='utf8_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

How do I select categories which have less than 3 subcategories (no depth),
and how do I select categories which have no child elements.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For less than three:

```
select parent.*
from category parent left outer join
     category child
     on parent.id = child.parent_category_id
group by parent.id
having count(child.id) < 3
```

For no categories:

```
select parent.*
from category parent left outer join
     category child
     on parent.id = child.parent_category_id
where child.id is null
```

Comment: It counts how much elements the category contains, not subcategories. Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: @zogby . . . I believe this answers your question.  Perhaps you should edit your question with some sample data in case I am missing something.